# Creating new columns to table

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

im trying to add new columns that i need it in my moduloe, bascailly i need to create 3 columns to the "sales_flat_order" table. I already created the php script that adds the sql and configure it on my config.xml, but after loading my shop, cleaning my cache, nothing is change, sorry if im missing something, this is my first module that im building and im still new in adding new tables or columns on magento.

My module structure is like:
- local/CompanyName/Mynewmodule/sql/invoicedocs_setup/mysql4-install-010.php

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->getConnection()
    ->addColumn($installer->getTable('sales/order'),'magnifinance_invoice_id', array(
        'type'      => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
        'nullable'  => true,
        'length'    => 10,
        'after'     => 'status', // column name to insert new column after
        'comment'   => 'Company Invoice ID'
    ))
    ->addColumn($installer->getTable('sales/order'),'magnifinance_invoice_url', array(
        'type'      => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        'nullable'  => true,
        'length'    => 255,
        'after'     => 'status', // column name to insert new column after
        'comment'   => 'Company Invoice URL Doc'
    ))
    ->addColumn($installer->getTable('sales/order'),'magnifinance_date', array(
        'type'      => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DATETIME,
        'nullable'  => true,
        'after'     => 'status', // column name to insert new column after
        'comment'   => 'Company Invoice Date'
    ));
$installer->endSetup();


- local/CompanyName/Mynewmodule/etc/config.xml:



       <config>
            <global>
                <models>
                    <magnifinance>
                        <class>CompanyName_Mynewmodule_Model</class>
                    </magnifinance>
                </models>


                <resources>
                    <invoicedocs_setup>
                        <setup>
                            <module>CompanyName_Mynewmodule</module>
                            <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                        </setup>
                        <connection>
                            <use>core_setup</use>
                        </connection>
                    </invoicedocs_setup>
                    <invoicedocs_write>
                        <connection>
                            <use>core_write</use>
                        </connection>
                    </invoicedocs_write>
                    <invoicedocs_read>
                        <connection>
                            <use>core_read</use>
                        </connection>
                    </invoicedocs_read>
                </resources>
...
```

Am i missing something?

Comment: Although you **can** ask this question here, since it is code based .. It's better asked on the Magento Board where Magento specific problems are asked ..  You might get a faster response.   Until then, Does this thread help? --> https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/65553/how-to-add-new-column-to-existing-table-in-magento-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Please, verify if you have the section in the config.xml

```
<modules>
   <CompanyName_Mynewmodule>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
   </CompanyName_Mynewmodule> 
</modules>
```

Try to rename the file `mysql4-install-010.php` to `mysql4-install-0.1.0.php` 
(The numbers in the name of the file should be the same as the version in the config.xml)

Please, make sure the table `core_resource` doesn't have the row: `invoicedocs_setup 0.1.0 0.1.0` before running the sql script. (If the row exists you will not be able to run the script. The row should appear after a successful installation)